# Phone Emulator Can Call WCF Service with Fiddler Attached, Throws NotFound Exception Otherwise

Tags: wcf, ssl, windows-phone-8, wif

I have created a WCF service and secured it using the new identity pipeline in .NET 4.5 with authorization provided by a token issued by an ADFS 2.0 server. The service is behind an SSL endpoint with a self-signed certificate.

I attached Fiddler to try and resolve an initial exception with consuming the service. This required enabling Fiddler's HTTPS decryption and installing the FiddlerRoot certificate on the phone emulator. I identified the problem and updated my code appropriately. The next time I attempted to consume the service, the code was successful. I detached Fiddler, and this is where the confusion starts. I continued receiving the same (misleading) exception:

`The remote server returned an error: NotFound.`

Thinking that perhaps this was an X509 chain validation problem, I installed the self-signed certificate on the phone the way I had with the FiddlerRoot cert. My results did not vary. The following things are true and do not make any sense to me:

- The service description page can be accessed at the endpoint address via the emulator's web browser
- IIS logs do not contain the request made to the service when the exception is thrown
- As a corollary, WCF trace logs also do not contain any information about the failed call

This behavior corresponds to behavior when the application is deployed to a physical device. I thought perhaps Fiddler was creating a proxy that had a network path available to it that was not available to the emulator, but this does not appear to be correct at first glance.

Debugging guidance or speculations regarding the source of the problem would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you're on the right track by suspecting the validation chain. However, installing the certificate on the phone might not be enough, you also have to check that it is attributed to the right domain. A common mistake for self-signed certificates is generating for localhost, then accessing them from another machine (and therefore another domain name).

Comment: @KooKiz Thanks for that thought. There have been some discrepancies as regards the CN on my certs and the FQDN I'm using to access the resource. I'll try it out and check back in.

Comment: @KooKiz You were spot on. Write it up as the answer and I'll be sure to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're on the right track by suspecting the validation chain. However, installing the certificate on the phone might not be enough, you also have to check that it is attributed to the right domain. A common mistake for self-signed certificates is generating for localhost, then accessing them from another machine (and therefore another domain name).